# Problemas para executar query (SELECT com INNER JOIN) que utiliza dados vindos de um formulário HTML

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo:

```
public function listarClientesBuscadosDoForm()
{   
    try
    {                       
        $c = new Conexao();
        $db = $c->conectar();

        $query = "SELECT a.cod, a.razao_social, a.cnpj, a.inscricao_estadual, a.servico, 
        b.tributacao, c.atividade_economica FROM clientes AS a 
        INNER JOIN tributacoes AS b ON a.id_tributacao = b.id
        INNER JOIN atividade_economica AS c ON a.id_atividade_economica = c.id
        WHERE a.razao_social LIKE :razao_social AND a.cnpj LIKE :cnpj
        AND a.inscricao_estadual LIKE :inscricao_estadual AND a.id_tributacao
        LIKE :id_tributacao AND a.id_atividade_economica LIKE :id_atividade_economica";

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);                   
        $stmt->bindValue(':razao_social',"%". $this->razao_social ."%");
        $stmt->bindValue(':id_tributacao ',"%". $this->tributacao ."%");                                                    
        $stmt->bindValue(':cnpj',"%". $this->cnpj ."%");
        $stmt->bindValue(':inscricao_estadual',"%". $this->inscricao_estadual ."%");
        $stmt->bindValue(':id_atividade_economica',"%". $this->id_atividade_economica ."%");                    
        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    

        echo json_encode($result);

   } catch(PDOException $e) {
                    echo "Erro: ".$e->getCode()." Mensagem: ".$e->getMessage();             
   }
```

}

Vocês me recomendariam uma forma correta de realizar esse tipo de consulta ? Esses dados que são passados para a query são vindos de um formulário (HTML) de consulta e eles podem vir vazios também (o correto é se vier vazio, trazer todos os dados). O problema é que eu uso 3 tabelas e inner join nessa consulta.

**Segue abaixo a descrição das 3 tabelas:**

**clientes**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**tributacoes**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**atividade_economica**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Formulário (HTML):**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vocês teriam ideia da forma correta de eu realizar essa query ou montar esse código ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiz uma coisa que não parece ser a melhor forma, porém foi algo que resolveu o meu problema. Ao meu ver resolveu de maneira pouco recomendável e errada (mas resolveu).

Tive que tirar os Binds e coloquei uma sequência de IF bem bizarra ali.

Minha intenção era manter os Binds e fazer da maneira correta, por isso abri a pergunta aqui. Mas como não obtive resposta, resolvi fazer dessa forma (estava com um pouco de pressa).

**Mas se aparecer uma resposta com a maneira correta de se fazer, eu aceitarei a mesma.**

**Código:**

```
public function listarClientesBuscadosDoForm()
{   
   try
   {                        
       $c = new Conexao();
       $db = $c->conectar();

   $razao_social = "";
   $cnpj = "";
   $inscricao_estadual = "";
   $tributacao = "";
   $atividade_economica = "";                   

   if($this->razao_social <> "")
   {
        $razao_social = " AND a.razao_social = '$this->razao_social'";                      
   }                    

   if($this->cnpj <> "")
   {
        $cnpj = " AND a.cnpj = '$this->cnpj'";
   }

   if($this->inscricao_estadual <> "")
   {
        $inscricao_estadual = " AND a.inscricao_estadual = '$this->inscricao_estadual'";
   }

   if($this->tributacao <> "")
   {
        $tributacao = " AND a.id_tributacao = '$this->tributacao'";
   }

   if($this->id_atividade_economica <> "")
   {
        $atividade_economica = " AND a.id_atividade_economica = '$this->id_atividade_economica'";
   }                    

   $query = "SELECT a.cod, a.razao_social, a.cnpj, a.inscricao_estadual, a.servico, 
             b.tributacao, c.atividade_economica FROM clientes AS a 
             INNER JOIN tributacoes AS b ON a.id_tributacao = b.id
             INNER JOIN atividade_economica AS c ON a.id_atividade_economica = c.id
             WHERE a.id IS NOT NULL $razao_social $cnpj $inscricao_estadual 
             $tributacao $atividade_economica ORDER BY a.razao_social";

   $stmt = $db->prepare($query);                                    
   $stmt->execute();

   $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

   echo json_encode($result);               
   } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Erro: ".$e->getCode()." Mensagem: ".$e->getMessage();             
   }
}
```